# How can we remove the emailid from default CC in Bugzilla..?

Tags: bugzilla

I am using the bugzilla for sending the bugs for development persons and then i given at configuration time default cc to one of the emailid but now i want to remove the default cc option for the particular user.Please give me intended path to resolve this issue Thank you one and all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default CC is defined for a component of a product. You can go to Administration -> components (linked from the paragraph of text under the Products heading) -> {name of product} to get a list of all components for the product, and the default CC for each. Edit each component that lists the user and remove them from the Default CC list.
Optionally, you can go Administration -> Users -> {user in question} to get a list of product responsibilities, that will show all the components they are a default CC for.